# How to create author.p12 file. I have received .csj file via mail

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I have an app for BB Web Works.I received the csk files via mail. While I build using command line it reports an error for missing author.p12 file. Please guide how to get the same. Thank.

Answer (score 5):

Create your Developer Certificate

To sign apps and create debug tokens, you'll need to use your BlackBerry ID token to create a Developer Certificate.

The following steps help you configure your computer to sign apps and create debug tokens. You should perform these steps only once.

**Before you begin:**

- Create your BlackBerry ID token.
- If you connect to the Internet through a proxy server, you must specify additional command line options to contact the Signing Authority Service. For more information about using a proxy server from the command line, see Using a proxy server from the command line.

  1. On the command line, navigate to the 
     `cordova-blackberry/bin/dependencies/bb-tools/bin` 
     subfolder of your BlackBerry WebWorks SDK installation folder.
  2. Create a Developer Certificate. The password you specify in the -storepass parameter allows you to use the .p12 file (the certificate file) to sign BAR files. You should protect the .p12 file and its password:
     `blackberry-keytool -genkeypair -storepass <keystore_pw> -dname "cn=<company_name>"`

**After you finish:**
 
After you run this command, the author.p12 file is created in the following folder:

Windows XP: `%HOMEPATH%\Local Settings\Application Data\Research In Motion`
Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8: `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Research In Motion`
Mac OS: `~/Library/Research In Motion`
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/beta/testing_and_signing_setup.html#kba1382104438461